# QtOpenGL, where is GLUnurbsObj?

Tags: qt, opengl, nurbs

In my qt5 code I've included  module and I would like to declare a `GLUnurbsObj` object but my IDE do not recognize it. Is glu.h included in QtOpenGL module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, glu.h is not included in the QtOpenGL module. In previous versions it was but has since been removed according to this post: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/14269. You should just be able to include glu.h yourself in your code.